# Progress Handler in android list base adapter

Tags: android, baseadapter

Below is the code snippet for progress handler in an activity:
It works fine with a class which extends Activity but I want to use it with a Baseadapter...

```
Handler progressHandler = new Handler() {       
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(WhiteboardAddPost.this);
            switch(msg.what){
            case 0:                 
                alert.setTitle("Add Post");         
                alert.setMessage(message);
                alert.setCancelable(false);
                alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.putExtra("OK", "ok"); 
                        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                        releaseMemory();
                        finish();
                    }
                }).create().show();                     

                break;
            case 1:                 
                alert.setTitle("Close");            
                alert.setMessage(message);
                alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        return;
                    }
                }).create().show();                     

                break;

            case 2:                 
                alert.setTitle("Close");            
                alert.setMessage(message);
                alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        return;
                    }
                }).create().show();                     

                break;                
            } 
        }
    };
```

How to use it in list view where we extends Baseadapter but not activity?

Further to elaborate the problem: In my list I am having a button attached with each item to delete that particular Item and when ever user click that delete button a request goes to server at this point of time I want to show an alert to show the wait message and when response comes then I want to show an alert with response message.

Comment: what does you want your list should do???

Comment: Further to elaborate the problem: In my list I am having a button attached with each item to delete that particular Item and when ever user click that delete button a request goes to server at this point of time I want to show an alert to show the wait message and when response comes then I want to show an alert with response message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your progressHandler will remain in your Activity class.
You should just send message when you get response and then this handler will work accordingly.